# python list and sublist

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have to check if list1 is contained in list2. It also should check if it appears in that order in the list as well. If it's true, it should return true and false if it doesn't.

```
def check(lst1, lst2):
for x in lst1:
    for y in lst2:
        xx = lst1.sort()
        yy = lst2
        if xx != yy:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I'm confusing myself with the for loops and also, I don't know where to go from here to fix my code. Pointers please?

example of what it should do:

```
  check([4,0],[9,1,4,6,8,9])
  True
  check([1,2],[2,3,1])
  False
```

Comment: In your example, why is the first check returning True? Zero is not in the second list.

Comment: If list1 has to be contained, in order, in list2, don't you lose the ordering when you sort()?

Comment: Why do you bother to loop over the two lists if you don't ever use the items `x` and `y` in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought the problem was begging to be solved recursively, so I did:

```
def check(needle, haystack):
  if not needle:
      return True
  try:
    offset = haystack.index(needle[0])
    return check(needle[1:], haystack[offset+1:])
  except:
    return False
```

Edit:

Brief explanation:

First we check if the list we're looking for is empty (this is important once we start calling ourselves), since all lists have the empty list inside it, we return True. Then we try finding the first item of the list we're looking for in the list we're looking at. If we find it, we then call the function again, but change the arguments a bit: we already looked at the first item of the 'needle' and saw it in the 'haystack'. So now we need to check if the remainder of 'needle' is in the remainder of 'haystack'. So we call the function again only with the remainder of both lists. The remainder of needle is everything but the first element, and the remainder of haystack is all items after the one we found. If we get to a point where the first list is empty, it means we found it in the haystack. If we get an exception, what we were looking for wasn't found, so we return False, which bubbles up the call stack and gets returned.

Comment: `index` returns the index of the item sought, and Python uses half-open intervals, so haystack[offset:] would not remove the sought item from haystack.

Comment: Thanks, was super easy to understand!

Comment: Wait no, spoke too soon, I was trying to take this code as a model for mine. Then once I got to 'return check(needle[1:], haystack[offset+1:])' I completely confused myself. Explanation? Sorry I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: I realise this is just a weird/unexpected question... I was hoping this would be False: `check([1,2,3], [1,1,2,2,3,3])` ie a sublist.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like:

```
set(lst1).issubset(lst2)
```

to see if lst1 is contained within lst2 ignoring order. If it passes the test that one list is contained within the other, then you could do something like:

```
ii = lst2.index(lst1[0])
if lst2[ii:ii+len(lst1)] == lst1:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

Originally I stated that the first check was irrelevant given the second, although you'd have to properly handle the `ValueError` if the first element of lst1 is not in lst2.

**Edit:**
Just as a side note, I compared a version of my code vs yan's and mine is significantly faster under almost all use cases, especially if len(lst1) is larger (up to 200x speedup vs yan's implementation). Give it a try with the `timeit` module.

```
def check(lst1,lst2):
    try:
        ii = lst2.index(lst1[0])
    except ValueError:
        return False

    if lst2[ii:ii+len(lst1)] == lst1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

As an explanation of how it works `ii = lst2.index(lst1[0])` finds the index in `lst2` that matches the first element of `lst1`. If that item is missing from `lst2` it catches the `ValueError` and returns `False`. If that element does exist, `lst2[ii:ii+len(lst1)] == lst1` compares all of `lst1` vs the sublist of `lst2` starting from the matched element and taking the next `len(lst)` elements.

Comment: Your solution intrigues me, especially this line: if lst2[ii:ii+len(lst1)] == lst1:. Do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: added actual implementation and explanation

Comment: Your answer may be faster than yan's algorithm, but that is because it is incorrect. You are assuming the elements in lst1 are consecutive in lst2. yan's is the traditional algorithm for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=[9,1,4,6,8,9]
>>> by_twos=zip(a, a[1:])
>>> by_twos
[(9, 1), (1, 4), (4, 6), (6, 8), (8, 9)]
>>> (4,6) in by_twos
True
```

Comment: I believe the OP's problem can include cases where the elements of the list being searched are not consecutive in the list being searched in. Also, not sure a length of two is specified.

Comment: @yan Sure, I thought I'd show how to solve one case, and the OP can generalize it however they like.

Comment: @the OP: you can call zip with more than two lists - so to get by_threes you could do `zip(a, a[1:], a[2:])` ...