# Any function which says if a sublist[i.e. something] exists inside a list or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any simple function which says if a sub-list [i.e Something or Anything] exits within a list or not ?

For Example:
a. Says there is a top list, i.e. top_list = []
b. Next check if some sub-list exits or not i.e. if top_list[0] exits or not ?
   Something like, top_list is [[]]. That sub-list can be just an empty list [] or a list with some number etc..

Just wanted to find if a sub-list exits within a list or not ? Kindly drop in your comments if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in Advance,
Vimo

Comment: The concept "sub-list" is rather vague. Please give better examples of what you mean: one where a sub-list exists and another where it does not.

Comment: Hello Rory..
a. Have a scenario where there is a top list say, top_list = []..
b. I wanted fill up only certain locations of the top_list.. Say, top_list[1] , then top_list[3] etc.. 
c. So in rest all places I will just fill up with empty list. For eg of top list as,
top_list is [[], [hello], [], [bye]] etc. 
d. So I come inside this particular operation and fill up only certain elements of the top_list. So before I fill up or append top_list[1], I wanted to check if top_list[0] exits, if not I will append top_list.append[]. So top list becomes [[]].
e.Then i will fill up top_list[[], [hello]]

Comment: So I just wanted to check if some sub-list exits in particular location inside a top level list. That sub-list can be anything ie. just an empty sublist [[]] or it can contain some name [[], [hello]] or some numbers [[], [hello], [5]]

Comment: I just simply tried :

cfg_array = []
for i in range(0, (loop_tmp-1)):
                if not cfg_array[i]: 
                    cfg_array.append([])
                    print "For Loop: Value of cfg_array is ",cfg_array

The simulation errors out saying "IndexError: list index out of range".. Which is true, because cfg_array[0] does not exits.. So how do I find if some sub-list exits or not inside the list.

Comment: a. Empty sub-list inside a top list. 
    top_list is [[]] . For my scenario this is also fine though the sub-list is empty, but then some sub-list exits.
b. Filled in sub-list inside a top list.
    top list is [[hello]]

Answer (score 0):

This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5148526/6194839
will check for a non-sequential list.

Checking for a sequential list I would just brute force it, looking through the list for an entry that matches the first in your sub-list, then checking for the rest.